# How do I save return function values to variables in Python?

Tags: python

```
def get_boundaries(target , margin) :
  low_limit = target - margin
  high_limit = margin + target
  return low_limit , high_limit
get_boundaries(100 , 20)
low =
high =
```

how do i save the return values to the variables? (Python)

Comment: Maybe `low, high = get_boundaries(100 , 20)`? I would suggest to read a good python introductory book

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you were looking for:

```
low, high = get_boundaries(100, 20)
```